# Передать количество повторений в наследуемый шаблон Blade

Tags: laravel, blade, laravel-8

У меня есть вот такая реализация наследуемых шаблонов (упрощенная разметка):

*chunks/incl.blade.php*

```
@for ($i = 2; $i <= $count; $i++) 
  <div id="card-guests-{{ $i }}" class="card-body booking-card-body d-none"></div>
@endfor
```

*layouts/parent.blade.php*

```
<div id="guests-info">
@yield('guest-count')
@include('chunks.incl', ['count' => $guest_count])
</div>
```

*child.blade.php*

```
@extends('layouts.parent')
@section('guest-count')
@php
$guest_count = 20;
@endphp
@endsection

@section('room-guests',20)
```

Все работает как надо, но мне не нравится реализация!

Видимо что-то я не доучил, что-то не дочитал ...

**Вопрос**

Как еще можно (более красиво) из шаблона `child.blade.php` передать количество повторений во включаемый шаблон `incl.blade.php`?